# Tautological one-forms and symplectic potentials on closed symplectic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I just want to clarify a point that I haven't seen made explicitly made:
there is no globally defined tautological one-form or symplectic
potential on a closed symplectic manifold (i.e. a compact manifold without
boundary). If there were such a one-form $\theta$ (in local coordinates, expressable as $p_i dq^i$) such that $\omega = -d\theta$, then on a $2n$ dimensional closed manifold $M$,

$$ V = \int_M \omega^n =  - \int_M d\theta \wedge \omega^{n-1} = -\int_M d \left( \theta \wedge \omega^{n-1} \right) = -\int_{\partial M} \theta \wedge \omega^{n-1} = 0$$

since $\partial M = \emptyset$ (and $d \omega = 0$). So we can't use the symplectic form $\omega$ as a volume form.

**EDIT**: I.e. $\omega$ being exact would imply that the volume of the compact manifold $M$ vanishes. This suggests (but does not constructively prove) that $\omega$ is not exact, and that *there is no globally defined tautological one-form or symplectic potential whose exterior derivative yields $\omega$ on a compact manifold*. Is there a more direct proof of the statement in italics, or does it suffice to assert that $\omega$ give rise to a volume form on $M$?

I'd take the 2-torus $T^2$ as an example of such an $M$.

I'm trying to square this with Darboux's theorem – presumably on $T^2$, taking $\omega = d\psi \wedge d\phi = -d(\phi d \psi)$ where $\psi, \phi$ are angular coordinates for the two cycles, is only true **locally** (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293599/in-the-2-torus-with-symplectic-form-omega-d-theta-wedge-d-varphi-is-the-vect?rq=1)), so there's no contradiction.

**EDIT**: To clarify, my understanding is that Darboux's theorem allows for $\omega = -d(\phi d \psi)$ on a given coordinate patch of $T^2$, but these local definitions cannot be made to agree with each other. Hence $\omega$ is not globally exact, and will yield a positive volume for $T^2$.

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: There does not seem to be a question here.

Comment: The reasoning is not correct. We cannot apply Stokes' theorem to conclude that $V=0$ because on the torus $\omega=d\psi\wedge d\phi$ is [not exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116869/does-torus-admit-symplectic-structure). It is formally true that $\omega=-d(\phi\,d\psi)$ but that tautological form is not continuous on all of $T\,.$ In short: $\omega$ is perfectly symplectic and the torus' volume form but it is not exact.

Comment: @KurtG. I think your comment means that my reasoning is correct -- or at least, what I have attempted to say above (however clumsily) is in agreement with your statement: there is no globally defined tautological one-form on $T^2$, as this would make $\omega$ exact and hence the volume vanishes.

Comment: Ok. We  are saying the same thing in our own words.

Comment: Here is an exercise you should be doing: Suppose that $M$ is a connected, compact, oriented manifold and $\alpha$ is a nowhere vanishing top degree form. Then $\int_M \alpha\ne 0$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I believe you are saying that if you presuppose $\omega$ is indeed a symplectic form on $M$, then $\int_M \omega^n > 0$ by the non-degeneracy property of $\omega$ (and sign/orientation convention). That's fair enough -- this then implies (by the argument I gave in my question) that $\omega$ can't be exact.

Comment: Right..........